# Why do Blender objects have one ShapeKey each?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, development

I am using Maya and Maya has BlendShape.

Maya's BlendShape is almost the same as Blender's ShapeKey.

And, Maya's BlendShape can transform multiple objects with one node.

However, Blender's ShapeKey always has one node per object.

[image]

In my scene, the skin and eyebrow objects are separated.

The skin and eyebrow objects have a ShapeKey block of the same name, "EyeBlinkLeft".

I want to move blocks with the same name at the same time.

For me, it's hard to move such ShapeKeys using Blender.

When changing the value of ShapeKey using Python, it is necessary to change the value of multiple ShapeKeys, so the process is slow.

I've tried using a driver to access multiple ShapeKeys from a single ShapeKey, which is also slow.

I have a question whether having one ShapeKey for each object is for some reasonable reason or whether development is simply not keeping up.

Or is there a better way to use multiple ShapeKeys?

If I want to make an add-on like lip sync, I need to change the value of ShapeKey several tens of times per second.

Then, the loop will be slowed down by the number of ShapeKey times the number of Block.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question but if your trying to apply multiple shapes to an object (such as left wink, right wink, combined blink) this can be achieved by targeting shape keys to different vertex groups - see this 2.5 minute youtube:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5I_xim7rXQ

Comment: Thank you. However, I looked at this video and did not understand. I've added a little more to the question text.

Comment: By which mean using drivers is slow? 30 sec setup?